# get lat lng from php array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in php and I would like to get the lat and lng.The array is

```
[results] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [geometry] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [location] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [lat] => 52.222306
                                    [lng] => 0.093831
                                )

                        )
                )
        )
```

Now there is only one element but it can be multiple.So I need to use foreach loop.The desired array structure should look like

```
array('lat=>'52.222306', 'lng'=>'0.093831', 'lat=>'xxx', 'lng'=>'yyy');
```

Can you please suggest me the best possible way.Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can't have duplicate keys in the carry... you probably want an array of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results in the array that you requested is not possible but this will give you an array of arrays.

```
 $coords = array();
 foreach ($results as $result){
     $coords[] = array("lat"=>$result->geometry->location->lat, 
                       "lng"=>$result->geometry->location->lng);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.You have saved my life.Answer accepted and unlimted thanks.